San Francisco to South Padre Island, TX overnight
On a Thursday in October, I would like to leave central San Francisco, CA after work (5+ PM) and get to South Padre Island, TX before noon the next day.  I'm OK to fly out of any of SFO, OAK, SJC and arrive at any of BRO, HRL, MFE, or even other major airports in Texas (IAH, HOU, AUS, SAT) and drive.  That's a lot of big airports with a lot of flights, but despite my best efforts with Rome2Rio, FlightConnections and Google Flights, this is proving surprisingly challenging:

The ideal solution would be to get there the same day and have a good night's sleep.  However, the absolute latest same-day connection appears to be AA SFO-DFW-BRO departing 4:09 PM, arriving 11:59 PM, with a very tight 40 min connection at DFW.  This would basically require leaving around 2 PM and thus taking half a day off.

The fastest possible overnight connection appears to be UA SFO-IAH-MFE, departing 11:59 PM and arriving at 8:50+1 AM, with a 1:43 layover in IAH.  However, the first leg is a torturous-sounding 3:40 overnight red-eye, which ensures I'll have very little chance to sleep and will be quite wrecked on arrival.

If I fly and drive, I could take United SFO-SAT departing at 6;25 PM, arriving 12:08+1 AM.  But then it's a solid 300-mi/4-hour drive from San Antonio to Brownsville in the dead of night. Maybe not so bad if I crash at San Antonio for a few hours first?


Am I missing any other options, and if no, which of these would be least bad?  Option 1 would be the clear winner if I can take the time off, but this may not be feasible and I may not know for some time.

How restrictive is the arrival in South Padre Island before noon? Would 12:30 or 1pm be OK?

Hoping to catch a rocket launch, which statistically has always been around 1 pm so far, so pretty restrictive -- and the earlier the better, really, since there's road closures etc.

Southwest has a lot of flights to Texas, and they aren't listed on the major search engines.
Somewhat similar to jcaron's itinerary #1, you have on Oct 10 WN 1474 departing OAK 7:00pm arriving HOU 12:40am+1, and then on Oct 11 WN 2477 departing HOU 8:40am, arriving HRL 9:50am.  I think you'll have to book them as separate one-ways instead of as a connection, though.

Google Flights tells me (on October 10th):


Departure from SFO at 6:35 pm
Arriving at 12:26 am in IAH
Spend a nearly normal night in IAH
Departure at 9:30 am from IAH
Arrival in HRL at 10:51 am
That still requires an about 1 hour drive to South Padre Island, so you would probably get there a little bit after noon.

Alternative:

It starts the same:

Departure from SFO at 6:35 pm
Arriving at 12:26 am in IAH

Then:

Spend a shorter but still viable night in IAH
Departure at 7:30 am from IAH
Arrival in MFE at 8:50 am
From there the drive is longer (1h30) but you should get to your destination before noon.


Hmm, interesting option indeed. But it looks like the only hotel actually connected to IAH (a Marriott) wants $281 prepaid nonrefundable for a room, and going anywhere else would require mucking around with shuttles/Uber and chew up an hour easy both ways...

There are plenty of hotels nearby in all price categories, a 6 minute drive away. It's actually probably faster getting there than to the Marriott inside the airport, I have no idea how you get there on foot, it does not seem to be connected to any of the terminals.

There's an underground people mover (the "Subway") linking the terminals and the hotel apparently, so it's easier to get to than it looks like on the map, but it remains pricey compared to the hotels outside the airport grounds. Check if you can get it with points or miles somehow, there are sometimes surprising deals.

Uber, Lyft, taxi to a nearby hotel
